# Move 3d object right/left + up/down independent of its rotation

Tags: opengl, 3d, rotation, translation, opentk

**Goal:**
Move a 3D object as if it is in 2D space (screen). So if the user moves the mouse left the object should move left (the same should apply for all other directions: right, up, down).

**Description:**
I am working with OpenTK (OpenGL - 3D space)
Since the object itself should always rotate around it's center I first apply the rotation then the translation matrix.

**What works**
With trying out I was able to get the translation for the x-Axis and y-Axis (both 2d space) working separately.

```
// works for x-Axis movement
var rotation = _control.Rotation;

// vector is a 2d vector that contains the vector from the mouse drag start position 
// (so the pixels the mouse was moved from the drag start to its current position)
// factor is a value that depends on the current zoom value - can be ignored for the problem itself
var xTranslationVector = new Vector3(
            vector.X * (float)Math.Cos(rotation.Y) * factor, 
            0,
            vector.X * (float)Math.Sin(rotation.Y) * factor);

// initial value is the original translation on drag start
_control.Translation = initialValue + xTranslationVector;

// vector for y-Axis
var yTranslationVector = new Vector3(0,
            -vector.Y * (float) Math.Cos(rotation.X) * factor,
            vector.Y * (float) Math.Sin(rotation.X) * factor);

// _control.Translation = initialValue + yTranslationVector;
```

Both work when used independent from each other.

**Questions**

1. How do I need to combine the xTranslationVector and yTranslationVector so that it would work as expected (multiplication doesn't work because any vector component could be 0 which results in no movement at all; addition does not work when the object is rotated around some axis partially)
2. I would like to understand what I am doing there, what are the mathematical terms i should look for to find explanations?
3. How can I do the same for rotation (f.e. the object is rotated 45° degrees around the y axis and I want to rotate - currently the object would tilt around it's x axis but i would like to tilt it always as if the object was not rotated around it's x axis - sorry not sure how to word this well)

Comment: I recommend to use 4x4 matrices for the transformations [`OpenTK.Matrix4`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/opentk.matrix4?view=xamarin-ios-sdk-12). The matrices can be concatenated by (multiplication) `*`-operator and set to a `mat4` uniform in the vertex shader. Use to transformation matrix to transform the vertex coordinate `gl_Position = transformMatrix * vertex`.

Comment: The matrices are generated based on the rotation and transformation vectors. The API abstracts this so you don't need to take care of this.

Comment: Which API? To do flexible transformations you've to combine multiple matrices for rotation and translation. As far as I know [OpenTK](https://opentk.net/) is just an C# OpenGL interface.

Comment: The api I use works on top of OpenTK and lets you simply specify the rotation and translation for a 3d object. Means: object.Position = new Vector3(x, y, z), object.Rotation = new Vector3(x, y, z) is what you specify. The matrix stuff is done by the internal api.

Comment: So the API seems to be inflexible. I recommend to calculate the model transformation by the use of `Matrix4`. Extract the translation and the [Euler angles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angles) from the final transformation matrix.

Comment: Thank you for your input. I am not sure how this would help me to solve the problem. Even if I would use matrices I still would have to calculate the matrix. The matrix is based on rotation and translation of an object so I would have the same problem just at another place of the calculation pipeline. The API allows access to the calculated model and view projection matrix. If I would "extract" the translation I would have a Vector3 again, or am I wrong. And I can write/modify shaders. Thank you for the link regarding euler angles, will look into it.

Comment: You've to know the current transformation of the model. "Concatenate" the new transformation to the current transformation. But there is too little information in your question to give a satisfying answer.

Comment: Maybe another view on the problem: Imagine a cube you want to move or rotate based on touch gestures. No matter of the current position/rotation of the cube you want that the cube moves in the direction the user slides the finger/same for rotation. How could this be done. The camera position is fixed.

Comment: I'vd a GitHub repository [Rabbid76/c_sharp_opengl](https://github.com/Rabbid76/c_sharp_opengl) with OpenTK examples. The project "OpenTK_orbit" does something like that. The relevant class is [NavigationControls.cs](https://github.com/Rabbid76/c_sharp_opengl/blob/master/OpenTK_library/Controls/NavigationControls.cs). But I think there is no short answer to this question.

Comment: But seems to be a good starting point. Thought it would be easier, since the code above partially worked as expected...

Comment: If you create the matrix yourself, then you can control the order the transforms are applied, which seems to be what you want.

Comment: First apply the current rotation of your object then translate it where you want it to be. If your camera if fixed, you should have its up and right vector (cross product between up and its viewing direction) then your translation becomes ```Vector3 translation = CameraRight* vector.x + CameraUp * vector.y```

Comment: Good to know. Thanks. I implemented it now in a different way: instead of using both axis (x and y to rotate the object) i rotate the object around y and for y i move the camera on a circle.